# Save Activity/Fragments state custom class

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a method to Save a Custom Class while rotating in an Android app. 
I want to save all instanced object called of the MatrixGame class...someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Fragment lifecycle is independent - when you're using a Fragment you can set it so it doesn't get destroyed upon configuration changes.

As you noticed, the Activity class gets destroyed and re-created when you rotate the app (or apply other configuration changes), if you want to persist the Activity state you can use sqlite and save whatever you need in the `onPause()` method. Then in the `onCreate()` method check the DB for last known state.

If you want to avoid saving the state "forever" (meaning, the user turns off the app and tomorrow when she turns it back on - you want to start fresh and *not* load the last known state) you can add a timestamp and set a threshold which, if passed, the data is considered stale and gets disregarded.

**Two comments:**

1. As @saprvade wrote, Fragments gets destroyed by default, in order to prevent it you should call: `setRetainInstance(true)`
2. In case you want to implement @saprvade's other suggestion (have the activity ignore rotation changes) you can see the following explanation of how to implement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/456918/1057429

Comment: Thanks for your help. So in my case I'm using a Fragment, but once rotating the device, class instanced on the fragment is recreated...how can i solve it?

Comment: @saprvade actually covered that in his answer: by setting `setRetainInstance(true)` you're making sure the fragment won't get destroyed.

Comment: Perfect, I've put it on the onCreate, but when rotating my custom class is redefined again! :(

Comment: @Altair remember that even though the Fragment won't get destroyed the Activity class will (and it's objects/resources will get reclaimed). So if you want to save objects that you've created within the Activity - Fragments won't help you - you'll have to use the other approach of persisting them.

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize your object. You can implement `Parcelable` or implement `Serializable` (`Parcelable` is several times faster). Then you will be able to put it in a `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore it in `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Also, you can serialize your object to `String`, e.g. json string.
Another option would be to store your object in a database or a file. It depends on your needs.

If you don't want to recreate this object on screen rotation you can change the lifecycle of your `Activity` by adding a configuration change flag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If we are talking about a `Fragment`, you can call `setRetainInstance(true)` to avoid fragment recreation on rotation.